# Angular Reactive forms - How can I set the default value of a datalist and still see the whole list in the dropdown?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, html-datalist

I'm trying to use a **datalist** in a reactive form in Angular because I want the user to add an option if it's not on the list. And I want to set the default value with the data I have, so I'm using formControl to set it, like this:

`category: new FormControl(myCategory, [Validators.required])`

But when I set the value, it only shows that one value in the dropdown, while if i set an empty string instead of "myCategory" I get the whole list.

[here you can see what happens with the value set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAkpu.png)

[here it's the complete list, but without the value set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIWPT.png)

This is my form:

```
<label for="category">Category</label>
            <input id="category" list="categories" class="form-control" formControlName="category">
            <datalist id="categories">
              <option *ngFor="let category of this.categoriesList" [value]="category">{{category}}</option>
            </datalist>
```

How can I set the default value and still see the whole list in the dropdown? Is there an easy way to do it?
Thank for your help.

Comment: I believe you can't as that's how `datalist` behaves. You might want to replace that with `select` or something similar.